# How to validate signature/consumer secret

Tags: php, oauth

I'm creating my own "Oauth service provider 'system'" and I have a doubt..

How should I validate the `oauth_signature` / `consumer_secret` .. I basically don't understand it.

My questions about it are:

1. When the `oauth_signature` parameter is sent to the service provider, is it sent already hashed with the signature_method or in 'plaintext'.
2. When it is received should I hash it ( or not, based on Q1 ) with the signature_method and then look if it matches with the one in the database?
3. When using [hash_hmac](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash-hmac.php) what should the parameters be? With this I mean, what is the data and what is the secret in the function

Sorry if it's complicated or I'm a huge noob - I've been looking for answers but can't find any clear ones.

TO NOTE: I am not using PHP's Oauth library/class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Well if `oauth_signature_method` says `PLAINTEXT`, the value for `oauth_signature` is just the plain signature base string. If it says `HMAC_SHA1` or some other cryptographic hashing algorithm, the client uses this algorithm to hash the signature base string using his secrets and then sends this hash as the `oauth_signature` parameter.
2. As the client already hashed the base string, you can just compare the sent value with the value you calculated on server side.
3. `data` is your constructed [signature base string](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5849#section-3.4.1), `secret` are the client's and token's secrets in [this format](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5849#section-3.4.2):

   ```
   {CONSUMER_SECRET}&{OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET}
   ```

Comment: What if it's the first request and I'm going to send the OAUTH Request tokens, what would I use as OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET?

Comment: You just let it empty and use `{CONSUMER_SECRET}&` (the `&` [MUST be included](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5849#section-3.4.2)).